# Error in training vs cross validation

Tags: python, machine-learning, h2o

I know this is more a machine learning question vs H2O but since I'm running this in H2O, I was wondering if anyone's seen this before. This is what my confusion matrix looks like with training data ( using a GBM model but happens in other linear models too)

```
        N       Y       Error   Rate
N       6921014.0       2076845.0       0.2308  (2076845.0/8997859.0)
Y       399597.0        8597833.0       0.0444  (399597.0/8997430.0)
Total   7320611.0       10674678.0000000        0.1376  (2476442.0/17995289.0)
```

For Validation:

```
N   Y   Error   Rate
N   4697621.0   263504.0    0.0531  (263504.0/4961125.0)
Y   148169.0    167182.0    0.4699  (148169.0/315351.0)
Total   4845790.0   430686.0    0.078   (411673.0/5276476.0)
```

There is a major jump in Y error rate. I don't see any overfitting attributes unless I'm missing something. Did anyone run into this before?
This seems to happen for Linear models as well.

Comment: Are you sure your test set is not different from your training set. If you look at the accuracy error, your test score is ever better than training... Also the balance between the two classes is a lot different between test and training cases. Please, double check that. Is it possible that you give us some information about your data and some code to see how you came up with those two confusion matrices?